# Trying to deploy a Node.js React application for web to Heroku or Github Pages, it works locally, and will not work on Heroku. Why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, github-pages, npm-start

**I am trying to deploy this:**
https://github.com/D474designs/youtube-react
I have used Express.js, and the stack it comes with, it works locally, just never on Heroku. I have declared the engines, and every other solution pertaining to the H10 error. It is odd because I have deployed to Heroku before without a problem.
**I also have a problem with my Github Page:**
https://github.com/D474/D474.github.io
I had it running after updating the React to use Prop-Types, I ran into a quota limitation on the API from YouTube, and now no matter what, even using a new API key, and waiting for the daily reset, the API will not pull.

**You can see the repository in question here:**
https://github.com/D474developments/D474

*The two issues are related, they are both using React, Node, and the YouTube Data API v3.

I am trying to update my Github page.*

```
web: node app.js
```

and

```
web: npm start
```

were both used, as I was using Express.js, as well as React-Scripts to serve the application. I am debating using a bin folder, and a www file, as that is what I used on the original Heroku application I deployed, which also used React, as well as Express.js. I declared engines in package.json in order to receive an error code after troubleshooting the Heroku deployment.

Here is the log from Heroku:

```
2020-06-17T08:59:57.387490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-06-17T08:59:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405721+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405744+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405744+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405745+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405745+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405746+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405747+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405747+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2020-06-17T08:59:59.405747+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-17T08:59:59.446202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-17T08:59:59.484953+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-17T08:59:59.487395+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-17T09:00:07.406170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178105+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178127+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178127+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178128+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178128+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178130+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178130+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178130+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2020-06-17T09:00:09.178131+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-17T09:00:09.227561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-17T09:00:09.283702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-17T09:00:56.159380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=reactrcore.herokuapp.com request_id=1a11d8fd-f9fe-49de-8ceb-53546a50370d fwd="187.131.207.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-06-17T09:00:56.536098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=reactrcore.herokuapp.com request_id=4d9ed39f-5dc3-4578-9d44-b79edf84dc26 fwd="187.131.207.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

This is the Express code I was trying to implement:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
 return res.send('pong');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, 
    () => console.log("Server is running..."));
```

This is a common problem online, and I have read all relevant articles regarding deployment of React applications using Node.js with both Heroku, and gh-pages, at least pertaining to my problem. I know there are complexities within node_modules, and specifics that must be met when deploying to Heroku, and using gh-pages.

Comment: You haven't committed the Procfile to your repo and you also haven't committed the code that uses express.js to the repo. You also haven't posted any logs (entire build log + entire log after starting application). Your second question should be posted in a new question but also here you are not providing any relevant information.

Comment: The Procfile is not the problem. I get the generic H10 error message in the Heroku logs, nothing more, and until I declared the version of Node I was using, I didn't even get that. I would just get the crash message with no error codes. The last Heroku app I deployed did not require engines declarations in the package.json file, so I know that is not the problem either. I was testing a new API key earlier today, and it was working fine, I am way below the limits, and it too has stopped working.

Comment: Noone can help you if you aren't providing the log files as well as showing the code that you used to make it run locally. (The express.js code isn't committed.) Information that you deem irrelevant can still be relevant. That's why you should always post log files regardless if you think they contain irrelevant information.

Comment: Ok, I have added what you asked for, and thank you, I really appreciate you, and everyone that makes Stack Overflow so amazing.

Comment: Your `app.js` does not exist.

Comment: I have it in src, it uses an index.html, and various other components. I have uploaded the repository in it's final form here: https://github.com/D474developments/D474
Should I move everything, or is there a way for me to control these variables. I know that I could not find a way in with gh-pages to set directories, and Heroku is not the most helpful when trying to deploy. I am willing to restructure, however this is pretty much the final structure of my repository before publishing, thanks again!

Comment: Try changing your command to web: node ./src/App.js

Comment: `github.com/D474developments/D474` your Procfile is a `.txt` file. There you are running `npm start` which is equivalent to `react-scripts start`. That command does not work on Heroku. You need to run an `express` server to host your static files. Again the express code is missing.

Comment: I had removed .txt in my implementation and did not save that version. It also does not have Express in either the node_modules, or saved in package.json. Heroku does not allow both package.json, and yarn.lock in deployments. Will just using web: node ./src/App.js work? Or should I implement Express? I have been trying variants all day; What would be my best option for deployment?

Comment: Changing the command to node ./src/App.js did not work.

Comment: I was hoping to deploy to Heroku without restructuring, I decided to not use only Github Pages due to issues with compilers, and restrictions with gh-pages. I can use Express, and if anyone is familiar with gh-pages, I am looking for the quickest way to get to deployment with minimal edits. I was running the v1 build completely on Github thanks to Babel and the ES2015 preset, a lot has deprecated since then, and I felt this update was necessary.

Comment: I added code for gh-pages, I would like to deploy code to both the index.html, and the secondary "full-screen mode" page.

Comment: The problem with gh-pages is it seems to only like vanilla flavors of React, Heroku relies heavily on Webpack for a clean deployment which is what I used in my previous Heroku deployment. Compilers are specific to both code, and deployment environment, and I seem to have exhausted possibilities at the moment and will have to deploy using my own hosting. Thank you for your help, I will let you know if I rebuild my site however due to using Redux, and a custom tech stack, I may just have to wait on this one...  
The site is currently operational with a revamped user interface at D474.github.io!

Comment: Also, you can visit my Heroku deployed application here: https://scriptlions.herokuapp.com/